# Email is not being received on 2nd account - Stack Overflow Account Merge Issue

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have two Stack Overflow accounts. One is signed up with Gmail, and the other is signed up with Facebook which is registered with a Yahoo email address.

Now I want to merge both accounts in one through Profile merge option via [Contact Form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). The issue is I am only receiving email on Gmail, but none of email is being received on other account which is a Yahoo email account.

Please help in this regard or suggest how can I merge these accounts into one.